# Is it possible to get filtered lookup on VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a filtered lookup on object level. And it is working as expected. When I use that standard lookup directly on VF page it is showing all values. The filter is not working on VF page. Is there any way to get filtered lookup on the page?

Comment: I think using `StandardController` on that VF page for that object should solve your problem.

Comment: I have already added Standard Controller on VF page.

Comment: Are communities enabled in your org? To which Object is the lookup to?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<apex:outputField>` tag with `<apex:inputField>` for the lookup field. And filter will start working.

Create a filtered lookup on the object level and use it on the page as below sample code.

Sample code for VF page: `<apex:inputField value="{!item.Account__c}"/>`

Comment: This would be a lot better with a code sample included to show how this would look in VF.

Comment: Create a filtered lookup on the object level and use it on the page as below sample code.
Sample code for VF page: <apex:inputField value="{!item.Account__c}" />

Comment: can you edit your answers to update details

Answer (score 0):

A filtered lookup only works in VF if the fields it's dependent on are also on the same page. They can be hidden if you prefer.